# Recommended books to purchase after a two-year break

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I am going to begin my master's degree after a two-year break since my bachelor's degree and I am a little bit scared that I forgot a lot of things.

Since I would rather purchase books than look back at my previous material, which books do you recommend me to buy in order to have most of the topics covered ? (analysis, algebra, probability,...) ?

I am looking for books that cover a lot of topics and that are good at explaining things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you doing pure or applied math?

Comment: Pure math. This master's degreee is a research-oriented one.

Comment: Matrix Analysis of R. Horn & C. Johnson is a great "bible" for linear algebra/finite dimensional normed vector space.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in reading [All the Math You Missed: But Need to Know for Graduate School](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521797071) by Garrity.

Book description:

> Few beginning graduate students in mathematics and other quantitative
>   subjects possess the daunting breadth of mathematical knowledge
>   expected of them when they begin their studies. This book will offer
>   students a broad outline of essential mathematics and will help to
>   fill in the gaps in their knowledge. The author explains the basic
>   points and a few key results of all the most important undergraduate
>   topics in mathematics, emphasizing the intuitions behind the subject.
>   The topics include linear algebra, vector calculus, differential and
>   analytical geometry, real analysis, point-set topology, probability,
>   complex analysis, set theory, algorithms, and more. An annotated
>   bibliography offers a guide to further reading and to more rigorous
>   foundations.

(I'm reading his new book Electricity and Magnetism for Mathematicians: A Guided Path from Maxwell's Equations to Yang-Mills , and I think he's a great author.  Very clear informal style.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this book looks very nice !